# How to rewrite a python function/method without comments and docstrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-syntax-tree

In the Python method below:

```py
def some_method (params):
    """ 
    Does an incredible thing.
    """
    if(params):
        # show current params
        print(params)
```

how could someone remove the **docstrings** (`"Does an incredible thing."`) and the **comments** (`# show current params`) using ast (abstract syntax tree)?

Resulting in:

```py
def some_method (params):
    if(params):
        print(params)
```

Comment: Where did you attempts fail? Also why do you want to remove docstrings- is there a practical reason?

Comment: I need to remove all non-code tokens for a deep learning task of understanding code.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/inspect.html) documentation, there the `getmembers()` method. It seems you can extract a methods docstring using the `__doc__` atrribute.